# Omit a word using grep

Tags: bash

I have tried this command three different ways and each time I have received and error message. I created the file `~/nostdhome.txt`, which contains lines from the `/etc/passwd` file which do not contain the text home. (implying that the associated user has a nonstandard home directory).

```
xargs grep -iL "home" /etc/passwd > ~/nostdhome.txt
grep -iL "home" /etc/passwd > ~/nostdhome.txt
grep -hn home /etc/passwd > ~/nostdhome.txt
```

Comment: You can use `grep -v`

Comment: no the -v is not giving me the correct out put

Comment: grep -v "home" /etc/passwd > ~/nostdhome.txt its not working

Comment: Are you still getting lines with `home`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `-L` suppresses normal output and instead prints the name of each input file from which no output would have been printed... Analogously, the `-l` option prints each file name from which the output *would* have been printed.

This should do what you want:
`grep -iv "home" /etc/passwd >~/nostdhome.txt`

Comment: feel free to point out the next time I do something like `grep | awk` :)